# Explain an MQL4 Cycle Identifier wHistory.mq4 ( a custom technical indicator )

Tags: indicator, algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4, mt4

As a `MQL4` newbie I have some questions and would be very happy if someone could answer them in detail.

**a)** Could someone please explain how the cycle identifier ( indicator for MT4, e.g. found [here](http://www.forex-tsd.com/adownload.php?attachmentid=179430) ) exactly works?!

**b)** Which value is calculated to decide if a signal is given?

**c)** Can a signal for a given candle also disappear ( repaint ) if this candle isn't the current one?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

### a) How it exactly works, Daniel?

Beware, the **`MQL4`** **indicators** have special mode of execution, which is different from an **Expert Advisor** type of `MQL4`-code.

That said, you will be able to read the code in context how it is being "progressively" calculated ( in increments, so as not to block the main flow of execution once an indicator is right added or modified ). This feature is unique to indicators, so care has to be taken if you reverse-engineer or design your own indicator from some high-level trading idea.

Would be fine to state, which part of the **`630 SLOC-s`** you have some problem with. Do not hesistate to post the code-block if you wish to go in detail decode efforts.

Anyway, be sure to carefully read the **`MQL4 Help`**, to understand **`OnTick()`** handling in Technical Indicator code ( `start()` in ***"old"*-`MQL4`** ). The process is rather sensitive to processing latency, as all Technical Indicators share one common thread in ***"new"***-`MQL4` execution engine ( MT4 Terminal <kbd>Build 6xx+</kbd> )

### b) Which value is calculated to decide a signal detection?

the signals are derived from code around **`MQL4-source line 400 .. 480`**

```
  if ( alertsOption == 0 ) {
       ...
     }
  }
  if ( alertsOption == 1 ) {                                          // buy
       if (   <{Major|Minor}>CycleBuy[SignalIndex] == -1
          &&  <{Major|Minor}>BottomAlertTime       <  Time[SignalIndex]
          ) { ... }
  }
  if ( alertsOption == 2 ) {                                          // sell
       if (   <{Major|Minor}>CycleBuy[SignalIndex] == 1
          &&  <{Major|Minor}>BottomAlertTime       <  Time[SignalIndex]
          ) { ... }
       ...
   }
```

### c) Yes, check comments

As a comment on **`MQL4-source-line 480`** expressively states, there are repaints and forthgoing algorithm tries to handle such situations.

Comment: Hi,

thanks for your detailled explanations. Maybe I didn't asked exactly what I want to know. As I wrote, I'am a MQL4 newbie. Thus, I can understand the code itself but not really the background or theory behind the CycleIdentifier's signals. Would it be possible that you or someone else could give me a brief overview what the idea behind this indicator is - for instance that a sell signal is generated if XXX = XX / XXX becomes >= XX (hope you understand it).

Once again, thanks in advance!
D

Comment: @DanielSchütz, **sell** alerts are generated in case **`alertsOption == { 0`** : all | **`2`** : sell only  **`}`**  && condition **`CyclePrice < PriceSell`**  , where **`CyclePrice = iMA( NULL, 0, PriceActionFilter, 0, MODE_SMMA, PRICE_CLOSE, pos );`** Symmetrically check the conditions for **buy** alerts.

Comment: Thanks again. You're great! How can I support you?!